# Create a new ec2 instance with ec2-classic option in VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc

I have machine in a VPC .

I ahve 2 question regarding this .

1) I want to move this machine from VPC to ec2-classic .
I read it somewhere its not possible . If thats correct then

2) I want to create a replicate a new instance with ec2-classic option but sad part is thats not coming even though some of my instances are configured witht hat option .

Comment: When was your account created? Does it show EC2 classic option when you launch an instance?

Comment: It shows , but i am not able to select it . My account was created a month back .

Comment: WHY do you wish to use EC2-Classic?

Comment: Don't want to add my instance in same vpc for security purpose and creation of other vpc will attract additional cost so ..

Comment: @Piyush what leads you to believe that creation of a VPC will add additional cost?

Comment: @mark : https://aws.amazon.com/vpc/pricing/

Comment: @Piyush the only items on that page are VPN connections and NAT gateways, both of which are completely optional.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK. New accounts **created in 2014 or later can only have EC2 VPC**, that is why EC2 Classic is greyed out for you. So you cannot launch an instance in EC2 classic.

And you cannot move an instance from anywhere to anywhere once it is launched. You can take an AMI of an instance and launch a new instance out of the AMI in the desired VPC/subnet.